# Python - Theano scan() function

Tags: python, theano

I cannot fully understand the behaviour of theano.scan().

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T


def addf(a1,a2):
        return a1+a2

i = T.iscalar('i')
x0 = T.ivector('x0') 
step= T.iscalar('step')

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=addf,
                   outputs_info=[{'initial':x0, 'taps':[-2]}],
                   non_sequences=step,
                   n_steps=i)

f=theano.function([x0,i,step],results)

print f([1,1],10,2)
```

The above snippet prints the following sequence, which is perfectly reasonable:

```
[ 3  3  5  5  7  7  9  9 11 11]
```

However if I switch the tap index from -2 to -1, i.e.

```
outputs_info=[{'initial':x0, 'taps':[-1]}]
```

The result becomes:

```
[[ 3  3]
 [ 5  5]
 [ 7  7]
 [ 9  9]
 [11 11]
 [13 13]
 [15 15]
 [17 17]
 [19 19]
 [21 21]]
```

instead of what would seem reasonable to me (just take the last value of the vector and add 2):

```
[ 3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use taps=[-1], scan suppose that the information in the output info is used as is. That mean the addf function will be called with a vector and the non_sequence as inputs. If you convert x0 to a scalar, it will work as you expect:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T


def addf(a1,a2):
        print a1.type
        print a2.type
        return a1+a2

i = T.iscalar('i')
x0 = T.iscalar('x0') 
step= T.iscalar('step')

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=addf,
                   outputs_info=[{'initial':x0, 'taps':[-1]}],
                   non_sequences=step,
                   n_steps=i)

f=theano.function([x0,i,step],results)

print f(1,10,2)
```

This give this output:

```
TensorType(int32, scalar)
TensorType(int32, scalar)
[ 3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21]
```

In your case as it do addf(vector,scalar), it broadcast the elemwise value.

Explained in another way, if taps is [-1], x0 will be passed "as is" to the inner function. If taps contain anything else, what is passed to the inner function will have 1 dimension less then x0, as x0 must provide many initial steps value (-2 and -1).