# Python theano.scan taps argument

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying desperately to understand the taps argument
in the theano.scan function. Unfortunately I'm
not able to come up with a specific question.

I just don't understand the "taps" mechanism.
Well I ok. I know in which order the sequences
are passed to  the function, but I don't know 
the meaning. For example (I borrowed this code from
another Question [Python - Theano scan() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718812/python-theano-scan-function)):

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T


def addf(a1,a2):
    print(a1)
    print(a2)
    return a1+a2

i = T.iscalar('i')
x0 = T.ivector('x0') 
step= T.iscalar('step')

results, updates = theano.scan(fn=addf,
                   outputs_info=[dict(initial=x0, taps=[-3])],
                   non_sequences=step,
                   n_steps=i)

f=theano.function([x0, step,i],results)

input = [2, 3]

print(f(input, 2, 20))
```

Setting taps to -1 does make sense to me. As far as I understand
it's the same as not setting the taps value and the whole vector 'x0'
is being passed to the addf function. x0 will then be added
with the "step" parameter (int 2 which will be broadcasted to the same size).
In the next iteration the result [4, 5] will be the input and so on
which yields the following output:

```
[[ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]
 [18 19]
 [20 21]
 [22 23]
 [24 25]
 [26 27]
 [28 29]
 [30 31]
 [32 33]
 [34 35]
 [36 37]
 [38 39]
 [40 41]
 [42 43]]
```

Setting taps to -3 however yields the following output:

```
[ 5  2  6  7  4  8  9  6 10 11  8 12 13 10 14 15 12 16 17]
```

I don't have any explanation how the scan function creates this
output. Why is it just a list now?
The "print(a1)" turns out to be as expected

```
x0[t-3]
```

Although I know that this is the value that a1 should have, 
I do not know how to interpret it. What is the t-3 th  value 
of x0?
The theano documentation
doesn't seem to be all to detailed about the taps argument...
so hopefully one of you guys will be.

Thx

Comment: If you look at the answer to the question you linked, you'll see that @nouiz has explained that passing anything other than `-1` to `taps` in `outputs_info` will result in the value passed having one less dimension than the initial value.  I believe the `tm3` value of `x0` at `t0` will default to the initial value specified in the `dict()` argument you passed, so the initial value of `x0`, though I'm not totally sure about this convention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To better understand the use of `taps`, you should first understand how `scan` uses the `outputs_info` argument altogether and how the provided values for it (`initial` to be exact) change the nature of the result.

`scan` expects you to provide the type of output you expect from this operation (unless of course you dont have any initial values to provide and simply mention `None`, in which case it will start the first round {`step`} and the output is not passed as a parameter to the `fn` in the successive rounds).

So `scan` is used for iterative reduction over the provided `sequences`. This means that at `step` *n* (and with no `taps` specified for either `sequences` or `outputs_info`), the given `fn` will be applied to the *n*th elements of each of the `sequences` along with the output(s) generated by the previous (*n-1* th) `step`. Hence the default value of `taps` for `sequences` is `0` and for `outputs_info` is `-1`.

Another way to look at it would be to consider all the sequences to consist of slices across their respective first dimension. So for a particular step, the current slice(s) of the `sequence(s)` and the output slice of the previous step are passed to `fn` and the computed output is added to the results as a new slice which would then be used for the next `step`. It is obvious that each of the output slices would be of the same shape. And if you are providing an initial slice as part of `outputs_info` then it should also have the same shape as that produced by the application of `fn`. In your example, if `output_info=[dict(initial=x0)]`, it would take `[2, 3]` as the first slice and use it for the first `step` as the argument `a1` to `addf`.

But quite often in signal processing (and elsewhere) you need more than just the last data points in time as causal information. Here I have used time just as a way to represent `steps`. Anyway, this is where `taps` is useful and helps in indicating exactly which data points from the `sequences` and `results` have to be used for the current `step`. In your example, this means that for the current `step` the 3rd last output should be passed to `fn`.

And this is where you need to be careful in describing `initial` for `outputs_info`. Because scan will first split the `initial` value into slices along the fist dimension. **Then the first slice among this set of slices would be considered the earliest slice** (3rd last in your example) **required to compute the output of the first `step`**.

Lets assume in your example, `taps=[-2]` and `input = [2, 3]`. In this case, scan will split the input into slices and use the first slice (the value 2 here) as the argument `a1` to `addf`. The resulting value 4 would be added to the output and for the next step, the slices would include [2, 3, 4] of which the value 3 is on the second last (-2) tap. And so on. However, with `taps=[-3]` and the same `input`, there is one value missing which is like saying that you had collected the values at times (t-3) and (t-2) but didnt collect the value at (t-1).

So if you reckon your output to be of a certain shape, and you require multiple taps of the output beyond -1, then the value of `initial` should be a list of elements of the required output shape **and** have **exactly** as many such elements as would be required to retrieve the earliest slice.

TLDR:
In your example, if you want to get 2d vectors as the result of each `step` and are using `taps=[-3]`, then `input` should be a list of 3 such 2d vectors. If you want to get single valued results, then `input` should be a list with 3 integers. A list with 2 integers does not make sense in this context at all. It would only make sense if `taps` is either -2 or -1 or `[-2, -1]`.